# How to get a list on an instagram accounts followers?

Tags: instagram

Is it possible to get a full list of all followers of a 3rd party Instagram user (eg not an account i control) through the instagram website ?

I know i can click followers, but it only loads around 100 followers then you have to keep scrolling to load the rest, for a large account this could takes ages.

Is there a phrase that can be appended to the end of the instagram URL to show the followers ?

I note that if you inspect the followers number at the top of the page it shows a URL like this `https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/followers/`but clicking that just loads the modal window where you get the 100 followers+ that you have to scroll through, if you try to navigate direct to the URL it redirects to `https://www.instagram.com/USERNAME/` ive tried with both JS enabled and disabled.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407851/instagram-api-how-can-i-retrieve-the-list-of-people-a-user-is-following-on-ins/62722236#62722236, this solution worked for me to get both followers and following of someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. So long as you are interested in the followers of Instagram accounts you know, this is possible. While a request to that URL will only return 100 followers, an automated repetition of that request along with some kind of scraping of the results modal will give you a full list of followers.
One way to accomplish this automation is by using [PhantomBuster's Instagram Follower Collector](https://phantombuster.com/phantombuster/7175/instagram-follower-collector#section_scrapeinstagramfollowersofinstagramaccountsyouknow). It is a paid service, but their 14 day trial should suffice.

[Helper Tools for Instagram](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/helper-tools-for-instagra/clibiflfecckdjnjcgcgjdknmbgceail) is another extension that can do this for you, but the free version has a limit of 10,000 users scraped.

If you know how to run code from your terminal, you could run a script locally that makes this repeated request for you. Here's [an example](https://github.com/tonoli/instagram-followers-scraper) that uses a Python script to make the repeated request and then scrapes the results using Selenium. The instructions [here](https://github.com/tonoli/instagram-followers-scraper#instagram-followers-scraper) are relatively straightforward.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there is a way.
1). Go to the account page of the user you want to see the followers of.
2). Click on the "followers" button.
All the followers will be listed

Comment: Although they are listed it only lists 100 or so at a time, if the account has got thousands of followers this doesn't really work. I addressed this in the original question.